# Coin address generation for all coins

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, address, vanity-address, address-generation

We are developing UI for coin trading. We have a plan to use  all the coins present in coinmarketcap. I am greatly confused how to generate coin address for all coins. I knew that from cryptsy.com, it is possible to generate address for all coins from bitcoin but I don't know how to implement it. Is there any easiest way to generate coin address for all coins or can anybody tell how cryptsy do this for all coins? We are doing this in Ruby. Can you please suggest some more ideas to implement this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look up vanitygen and how to use it for altcoins; that should give you an idea

Comment: The following is not language specific, also a similiar process for most altcoins. Read up on it's key differences or even look at the source code of the altcoin. https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Think there is some confusion here regarding the generating of new address's within a wallet and the generation of Vanity Address's. Based on

> Is there any easiest way to generate coin address for all coins or can anybody tell how cryptsy do this for all coins?

I Believe what you are asking is how can you setup a system which enables users to have address's for all the different alt-coins.  This being the case you cannot do this using JUST the bitcoin software, you would need a copy of the client software for each coin you would like to generate address's for.  Then assuming you are trying to setup a Cryptocoin trading exchange similar to Cryptsy then from within the balances page (using Cryptsy as the example) when you click on a currency here and go to "Deposit / Autosell "  It then has the "Generate New Deposit Address" This will most likely be making a call to the client for the currency you have selected like:

altcoind getnewaddress $cryptsy-username

or something similar obviously altcoind would be amended forthe currency you actually wanted to generate the address for,  and the actual code to make the RPC call will be very differnt from the above, and will vary in different languages.  A good guide on implimenting RPC call's into code can be found here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC).